# Javascript Function Output

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing how to maniupulate data in JS in this article: http://learnjsdata.com/combine_data.html

```
var articles = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "vacuum cleaner", "weight": 9.9, "price": 89.9, "brand_id": 2},
    {"id": 2, "name": "washing machine", "weight": 540, "price": 230, "brand_id": 1},
    {"id": 3, "name": "hair dryer", "weight": 1.2, "price": 24.99, "brand_id": 2},
    {"id": 4, "name": "super fast laptop", "weight": 400, "price": 899.9, "brand_id": 3}
];

var brands = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "SuperKitchen"}, 
    {"id": 2, "name": "HomeSweetHome"}
];

articles.forEach(function(article) {
    var result = brands.filter(function(brand){
        return brand.id === article.brand_id;
    });

    delete article.brand_id;
    article.brand = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].name : null;
});
```

I'm confused with the last part: article.brand = (result[0] !== undefined) ? result[0].name : null;

I understand the conditional operation: it wants to have null value if result[0] is not defined. But I'm wondering what result[0] refers to. I thought it would take first object: {"id":2, "name": "HomeSweetHome"} so there should be for loop to iterate all objects in order to see if objects meet the condition? Could you inform me what I'm missing or/and what result[0] refers to?

Thanks,

Comment: Your result array is already filtered.

Answer (score 1):

result[0] will be undefined in case there is no element in result. result is expected to be an array of brands filtered by the filter operation

The filtered array result will have same brand as that of the current article in the outer foreach loop. The filter condition is going to achieve that.

It looks like in this particular case you will get only one element in result array always as there are unique brand ids. It might have more elements in case of duplicated brand ids.

result[0] points to first element in the array result

Comment: Could you exaplin in more details? What does this [0] part do?

Comment: OK I have added more text to answer.